# HTML purifier - allowing inline css style background-image: url()

Tags: css, url, background-image, inline, htmlpurifier

how do i enable background-image css inline style?

I've set these config, but still doesn't work;

```
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array('http' => true, 'https' => true));
$config->set('CSS.Proprietary', true);
$config->set('CSS.Trusted', true);
$config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', array('background-image'));
```

from this input for example:

```
<div style="background-image: url('https://somedomain.com/image.jpg');"></div>
```

the result always like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url(;"></div>
```

what did I miss??

UPDATE:

I would like to apologize. It seems that I was wrong at understanding the problem. It turns out the problem is not with the HTML purifier, but with PHP PDO or bind paramter. So htmlpurifier change the `'` sign to `&quot;`, but when inserting to database the PHP PDO bind parameter seem to omit  everything after `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the single quote?

```
<div style="background-image: url(\'https://somedomain.com/image.jpg\');"></div>
```

I guess that's why the code breaks right after the opened parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
<div style="width:120px; height:40px; background:no-repeat url('http://static.reddit.com/reddit.com.header.png');">

</div>
```

You can check this 
[Answer](https://codepen.io/imnavanath/pen/NyOygm)